# LazyVerticalGrid for paging items in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging

I'm currently using paging items (`LazyPagingItems`) in `LazyVerticalGrid` via below extention function and it works fine.

```
inline fun <T : Any> LazyGridScope.items(
    items: LazyPagingItems<T>,
    crossinline itemContent: @Composable LazyGridItemScope.(item: T?) -> Unit
) {
    items(count = items.itemCount) { index ->
        itemContent(items[index])
    }
}
```

However, i want to make use of other parameters that `LazyLazyout` provides like `key`, `span` etc and tried below function.

```
inline fun <T : Any> LazyGridScope.items(
    items: LazyPagingItems<T>,
    noinline key: ((item: T?) -> Any)? = null,
    noinline span: (LazyGridItemSpanScope.(item: T?) -> GridItemSpan)? = null,
    noinline contentType: (item: T?) -> Any? = { null },
    crossinline itemContent: @Composable LazyGridItemScope.(item: T?) -> Unit
) = items(
    count = items.itemCount,
    key = if (key != null) { index: Int -> key(items[index]) } else null,
    span = if (span != null) { { span(items[it]) } } else null,
    contentType = { index: Int -> contentType(items[index]) }
) {
    itemContent(items[it])
}
```

When i use that function with `key`, it shows errors that `Type mismatch: inferred type is Long? but Any was expected`.

```
items(items = products, key = { product -> product?.productId }) {
//Content
}
```

I guess this is due to declaration of `public class LazyPagingItems<T : Any>`. How do I resolve it to use all parameters with paging items ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `product?.productId` you are trying to pass an optional `Int?` value, while `key` expects a non-optional `Any` value.

When you pass `key = null` to the computation block, under the hood it creates a unique key for each object depending on the index. A particular item key cannot be `null` as that would make it equal to other item keys, which is forbidden.

You can make call `key` only for non optional items, and provide `index` as the default value for optional case:

```
inline fun <T : Any> LazyGridScope.items(
    // ...
    noinline key: ((item: T) -> Any)? = null,
    // ...
) = items(
    // ...
    key = if (key != null) { index: Int -> items[index]?.let(key) ?: index } else null,
    // ...
```

Usage:

```
items(items = products, key = { product -> product.productId }) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggle with a "Key" problem since I updated from androidx.compose *"1.3.0-beta03"* to *"1.3.0-rc01"*.

I use *LazyPagingItems* for a *LazyVerticalGrid* and i add items like this in the *LazyGridScope*:

```
(pagingData: Flow<PagingData<DangerItem>>){
val feedData = pagingData.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
items(feedData.itemCount,
        // to maximize the performance add a unique key
        // as fallback use index of element
        key = { index ->
            feedData[index]?.code ?: index
        },
        contentType = { idx ->
            if (feedData[idx] != null) 1 else 0
        }
    )
```

But since the library update, when I filter the content (so the paging items are updated in the flow), it throws an Exception. This exception wasn't thrown in the beta03 library version.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed requirement. 
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridSpanLayoutProvider.getLineIndexOfItem--_Ze7BM(LazyGridSpanLayoutProvider.kt:174) 
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridItemPlacementAnimatorKt.lastIndexInPreviousLineBefore(LazyGridItemPlacementAnimator.kt:489)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridItemPlacementAnimatorKt.access$lastIndexInPreviousLineBefore(LazyGridItemPlacementAnimator.kt:1)
```

Because paging data is changing and elements become null while loading I can't supply a unique key, the App crashes. Is this now a bug in the library or what exactly is the best practice when using *LazyPagingItems* that can change over time.

[image]

I found this workaround.

```
key = { idx ->
                if (feedData[feedData.itemCount - 1] == null || feedData.itemCount <= 1) idx
                else feedData[idx]?.code ?: idx
            },
```